# Printing PDF in an iframe throws an error in Firefox and IE(working fine in chrome)

Tags: iframe

Need Help!

I have opened a PDF inside a iFrame, while printing the PDF it's throwing the following error in Firefox and IE, the same code working fine in chrome.

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'print'
window.frames["printf"].print(); // printf is my iFrame name.
```

Following code I used for the print.

```
   //print pdf file
    $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
        window.frames["printf"].focus();
        window.frames["printf"].print();
    });
```

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks..

Comment: is maybe cross domain?

Comment: no, it's not related to cross domain.